# scapy sniff using remote host's interface

Tags: python, scapy, tcpdump

I want to sniff some packets using scapy, but not from the interface of own host, but want to sniff from a remote host (e.g. 192.168.1.x) and its interface. is this possible with python and scapy and/or paramiko tunnel with tcpdump?

```py
sniff(prn=packet_callback, iface=iface, filter=bpf_filter, count=0)
```

it would be happy if I can replace `iface` with proper function or virtual interface.
The remote is a linux box, `tcpdump` installed, so I can do something like following over ssh

```sh
$ tcpdump -i eth1 -U -w -
```

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Are the target and the attacker on the same subnet?

Comment: Hi @Thecave3, no they are in the different networks.